# What happens when uncertainty in position approaches 0 in Heisenberg’s equation?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, heisenberg-uncertainty-principle

In class today we were taught about Heisenberg’s equation, $\Delta x\Delta p\ge\frac{h}{4\pi}$.

What happens when one of these uncertainties approaches zero? If we can predict the momentum exactly, change in position approaches infinity - that much I’m okay with. But what about the other way - if we can predict the position exactly, change in momentum ought to approach infinity, which should be impossible given a hard limit on velocity at $c$.

Am I misunderstanding something here?

Comment: Another fun thing to think about: What if the size of the universe is finite? What does that mean for the limit $\Delta p\rightarrow 0$?

Comment: @JahanClaes I was always taught that when the unobservable universe is considered, the universe is infinite; is that not correct, or at least not universally agreed upon (pardon the expression)?

Answer (score 3):

I suspect your mind is captured
by the Newtonian relation between velocity and momentum
$$p=mv \tag{1}.$$
And from that you concluded $|p| < mc$.

But actually this relation (1) is an approximation, true only
for small velocities ($|v| \ll c$).
For larger velocities you need to use the exact Einsteinian relation
(from the special theory of relativity):
$$ p = \frac{mv}{\sqrt{1 - \frac{v^2}{c^2}}}. \tag{2}$$
For small velocities $v$ relation (2) can be approximated by (1).

But for bigger velocities $v$ you get significant deviations.
Especially, for $v \to \pm c$ you get $p \to \pm\infty$.
And therefore $\Delta p \to \infty$ is possible.

Comment: It feels odd combining relativity with QM like this, but I guess this makes sense. So what happens when I plug this into De Broglie’s equation? Is it valid to say that $\lambda=\frac{h}{\frac{mv}{\sqrt{1-\frac{v^2}{c^2}}}}$?

Comment: @DonielF Yes, that's correct. You need to use the relativistic momentum $p$ in De Broglie's equation.

Comment: Velocity doesn't exist in quantum mechanics since the notion of a trajectory of a particle is disproved out of existence with the non-commutative $\hat{x},\hat{p}$. Of course, one can define an artificial velocity in quantum mechanics as $\hat{v}=\frac{\hat{p}}{m}$. Then, by definition, $\hat{p}=m\hat{v}$. But again, due to a lack of a natural notion of velocity, this is an ambiguous definition. Do you rigidly define $\langle x|\hat{v}|y\rangle=\frac{\hbar}{mi}\frac{\partial}{\partial x}\delta(x-y)$? Or, do you define $\hat{v}=\frac{\hat{p}}{m}$ where $[\hat{x},\hat{p}]=i\hbar$?

Comment: Also, mixing special relativity with quantum mechanics is a painful idea. A relativistic quantum theory of a single particle is inconsistent, i.e., it doesn't exist. A naive Schrodinger equation with relativistic energy-momentum relation leads to non-locality and a somewhat clever Klein-Gordon version of the equation leads to negative probabilities. The super-clever Dirac version of the equation leads to an impressively consistent theory but the spectrum of the Hamiltonian is not bounded from below and thus, it is not physical.

Answer (score 2):

The first point to make is that the QM you are studying is almost certainly nonrelativistic quantum mechanics, described with the Schrodinger equation, which doesn't have a notion of $c$ just like Newtonian mechanics doesn't have a notion of $c$. It's a theory that works well at low velocities and breaks down at high velocities. So you shouldn't expect ALL of the predictions you see to be consistent with relativity.

---

On the other hand, the Heisenberg uncertainty relation IS consistent with relativity, because it doesn't come from the non-relativistic Schrodinger equation. It comes from the canonical commutation relations between position and momentum. These commutation relations are common to the Schrodinger, Klein-Gordon, and Dirac equations, so they hold for both relativistic and non-relativistic theories. You are bothered that the momentum could go to infinity, but that shouldn't bother you at all, because momentum *can* go to infinity in relativity. It's *velocity* that has to be finite. As a reminder, in relativity the relationship $mv=p$ breaks down at large momentum; instead, you have $\gamma mv=p$. If you work it out, you'll see that as $v\rightarrow c$, $p\rightarrow\infty$, so that arbitrarily large $p$ is completely consistent with relativity.

Comment: Well, when the particle is prepared in a state with $\Delta x=0$, the momentum doesn't go to infinity. It simply doesn't exist. The state is a position eigenstate and since the momentum operator doesn't commute with the position operator, a position eigenstate doesn't have a momentum. It is a category mistake to speak of the momentum of a state prepared with $\Delta x=0$. The uncertainty in momentum is what goes to infinity and that corresponds to all the momenta being equally likely to be found if a momentum measurement were to be performed on the prepared state.

Comment: Now, it is crucial for the Heisenberg principle to work that when $\Delta x=0$ (and thus when all the momenta are equally likely to be found if a momentum measurement were to be performed), $\Delta p$ diverges. For this to happen, the spectrum of the momentum operator has to be unbounded (otherwise $\Delta p$ would be bound to be finite). So, this is where OP's question should ideally come in. How is an unbounded spectrum of the momentum operator consistent with a speed limit?

Comment: @DvijMankad That's exactly right. I interpreted OP as understanding what $\Delta p$ means, and just asking how $p$ could be unbounded. But this is an important thing to keep in mind in general.

Answer (score 0):

I think you misunderstand it. The principle reflects the fact that a particle does not have a position and a momentum simultaneously. If you measure its position it no longer has a momentum. If you then measure its momentum you will obtain an unpredictable value. That value need not be a large one, even if you have just nailed down its position very accurately- ie even if DX approaches zero. It just means that the momentum you will measure might fall anywhere in a very large range of values between zero and c.

Comment: But analytically where does c come out of the equation?

Comment: Hi DonieIF, Sorry, I should have added that where the uncertainty implies the possibility of very high speeds you need to use the relativistic version of the equation. You can Google it easily enough.

Comment: No, it is absolutely essential that the spectrum of the momentum operator be unbounded for the Heisenberg principle to work. Otherwise, by definition, $\Delta p$ cannot diverge and the Heisenberg uncertainty principle would be violated for states in which $\Delta x=0$. So, the OP is correct in asserting that the form of the Heisenberg principle immediately implies that there exist states in QM with indefinitely large momentum (however, I agree with you that OP seems to have misunderstood what the uncertainty principle actually means).